Probability of a Bernoulli r.v. conditioned on the sample proportion estimate of its parameter
In my problem, there is a collection of $n$ random variables $X_1, …, X_n$, being all them independent and identically distributed according to a Bernoulli distribution of parameter $p$ ($p \equiv P\{X_i=1\}$).
There is another random variable defined as $S \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n X_i/n$.
I wonder about the conditional probability $P\{X_i=1| S = s\}$ for any $i=1,..,n$ and $s\in \mathbb{N}$.
My intuition tells me that $X_i$ should be conditionally independent of the r.v. $S$ and thus $P\{X_i =1| S = s\} = p$.
However, if $S=s$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = s·n$, and this makes me wonder whether the probability of $X_i$ conditioned on $S=s$ could be estimated in a frequentist manner as $s$, that is, $P\{X_i=1 | S = s\} = s$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Each $X_i$ is not independent of $S$: you know $S$ is the average of the $X_i$s so they are clearly dependent and clearly have a positive correlation.

Your $P(X_i=1 \mid S = s) = s$ is correct
because $S=s$ implies that there were in total $ns$ cases of $X_i=1$ and $n-ns$ cases of $X_i=0$
and since the various $X_i$ are exchangeable (even with the conditioning)
you have for each $i$: $P(X_i=1 \mid S = s)= \frac{ns}{ns+n-ns}=s$.

I suppose that you already got a course on conditional expectation. The usual strategy is to find the function $f$ such that $f(S) = P(X_i = 1 |S)$. By the definition of conditional expectation and since $S$ only takes a finite number of values, we have
$$ P(X_i = 1, S=s) = E[f(S)1_{S=s}] = f(s)P(S=s) $$
To lighten the notations, we can set $i=1$ and assume $p = 1/2$ without loss of generality. We calculate the left hand side:
$$ P(X_i = 1, S= s) = P(X_i = 1, X_2+...+X_n = ns-1) = \frac{1}{2}P(B_{n-1} =ns-1) = \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n-1}{ns-1}  $$
where $B_{n-1}$ is distributed as $Bin(n-1,1/2)$ and the right handside:
$$ P(S=s) = \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{ns}.$$
From these calculations, you see that $f(s) =s = P(X_i = 1|S=s)$.
